# SQL: INSERT INTO table(...) VALUES (...) with data retrieved from other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-insert

Thank you for passing by. I know basic SQL syntax and I can't seem to find a way to accomplish this task.

I need to create a stored procedure which inserts data from one table in another, amid retrieving data from many others. Suppose I have these tables with columns:

1. `users`

   - name (varchar)
   - sub_id (int)
   - dub_id (int)
2. `tmp_users`

   - name (varchar)
   - sub_name (varchar)
   - dub_name (varchar)
3. `subs`

   - id (int)
   - name (varchar)
4. `dubs`

   - id (int)
   - name (varchar)

Translated in pseudocode I should do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO users (name, sub_id, dub_id)
ALL ROWS FROM tmp_users VALUES (
    name = tmp_users.name, 
    sub_id = SELECT id FROM subs WHERE tmp_users.sub_name = subs.name,
    dub_id = SELECT id FROM dubs WHERE tmp_users.dub_name = dubs.name,
)
```

In wording I need to insert into `users` all rows from `tmp_users`, to keep the col `tmp_users.name`, but retrieve the afferent `id`s of all other tables based on `*_name` column. How should I approach this task?

Comment: there are *two* forms of INSERT statement..   `INSERT ... VALUES` and `INSERT ... SELECT`  ... looks like you are wanting the second form, which does not use the VALUES keyword ... first write a SELECT statement that returns the set of rows you want to insert, get that tested. Then you can precede the SELECT with `INSERT INTO foo (fee, fi, fo, fum)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for [the `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html):

```
INSERT INTO users (name, sub_id, dub_id)
SELECT 
    tu.name,
    s.id,
    d.id
FROM tmp_users tu
LEFT JOIN subs s ON s.name = tu.sub_name
LEFT JOIN dubs d ON d.name = tu.dub_name
```

This brings all rows from `tmp_users`, then attempt to recover the corresponding `sub_id` and `dub_id`. For each row returned by the `select`, a record is inserted in `users`. A good thing about this syntax is that you can run the `select` query independently first, to see what would be inserted.